# Poping a list using for each loop in python3 does not empty list?

Tags: python, for-loop

```
import random

class card:
  suit = ['♥','♦','♣','♠']
  card = ['K','Q','J',10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,'A']

class deck(card):
  def __init__(self):
    self.d1 = []

    for x in self.suit:
      for y in self.card:
        self.d1.append(x+str(y))

  def mix(self):
    random.shuffle(self.d1)
    
  def pop(self):
    return self.d1.pop()

d = deck()

#print(d.d1)

#d.mix()

print(d.d1)

for x in d.d1:
  print(d.d1.pop())

print(d.d1)
```

for each loop in the code only `pop()` out half the elements in the list.  i.e. if 52 cards are in the loop only 26 are getting `pop()` out of the list

Answer (score 0):

You are removing out of the same list you are iterating over. quickest change is this:

```
for x in list(d.d1):
  print(d.d1.pop())
```

Comment: okay but what is the logic for the solution

Comment: Good question. If you iterate over a list and at the same time remove elements, the size of the list changes and you will not reach the end. `list(d.d1)` makes a copy. So you iterate over the copy, but remove from `d.d1`.

Answer (score 0):

it is because "pop method of the list" changes the list and list size. While when we use it like

```
for i in range(0, len(d.d1)):
  d.pop()
```

or

```
while True:
  try: 
    d.pop()
  except:
    break
```

it is ok.